# SyntaxError when using try/catch with aync/await in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner in Node Js. I am not able to figure out why the below code gives syntax error with `catch()`.I have upgraded the Node JS V14. Any help will be appreciated here

```
async function demoPromise() {
    try {
        let message1 = await myFirstPromise;
        let message2 = await helloPromise();
        console.log(message2);
    } catch ((error) => {
        console.log("Error:" + error.message);
    })
}

(async () => {
    await demoPromise();
})();
```

Error:

```
nodejs\mark\asyncAwait.js:7
    } catch ((error) => {
             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: It's a syntax error because that's simply not the syntax for catching an error. You've started an arrow function for some reason; are you confusing this with the `.catch` method on a promise object?

Comment: remove the arrow and the closing `)`: `} catch (error) { ... }`

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe for your quick reply on this. yes exactly, I got confused with promise catch vs try-catch with async/await. it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catch` doesn't expect a function, it's just a special syntax to detect the error:

```
try {
  
} catch(error) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax checker of node is already telling you where it encountered a syntax issue.

Look for the **carrot sign ("^")** in your provided output. It shows exactly when the process stopped. It was looking for anything except an open parenthesis and it found one, thus thrown the error.